# Dynamic creation of properties for export script

Tags: scripting, python, add-on, properties

This time I have a question about Properties in Blender. I want the operator window of my add-on to have one `BoolProperty` per action defined in `bpy.data.actions` and I want them to have the names from `bpy.data.actions.keys()`. I googled a bit and tried some stuff, but it wont work, theres allways something wrong, so is this even possible and can someone give me some hints on how to do it?

```
class ExportTSA(bpy.types.Operator, ExportHelper):

    actionprop0 = BoolProperty(name=bpy.data.actions.keys()[0],description="Exporet this action",default=True)
    actionprop1 = BoolProperty(name=bpy.data.actions.keys()[1],description="Exporet this action",default=True)
    actionprop2 = BoolProperty(name=bpy.data.actions.keys()[2],description="Exporet this action",default=True)
    actionprop3 = BoolProperty(name=bpy.data.actions.keys()[3],description="Exporet this action",default=True)

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout

        row = layout.row()
        row.prop(self,"actionprop0")
        row = layout.row()
        row.prop(self,"actionprop1")
        row = layout.row()
        row.prop(self,"actionprop2")
        row = layout.row()
        row.prop(self,"actionprop3")
```

Heres a simplified version of my class, to demonstrate the idea. Instead of making hardcoded props like actionprop0, actionprop1... I want it to be dynamic in a way that it creates an automatic list, assigns the correct names, registers each one and draws them. I also found that you get into trouble when using `bpy.data.actions` where I used it, after I googled it it turns out that blender seems to be not fully initialized at that point so that causes errors, which might lead to additional problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think dynamic property creation is possible. I've tried it before, and Blender always complains:

```
rna_uiItemR: property not found: [property_name]
```

An alternative way would be to put the property in [`bpy.types.Action`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_67_1/bpy.types.Action.html) instead, so every actions already have the property. Then it's only a matter of displaying it.

```
import bpy

class EX_dynamic_property(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_idname = 'EX_dynamic_property'
    bl_label = 'Dynamic Property'
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'TOOLS'

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        for action in bpy.data.actions:
            layout.prop(action, 'EX_export_this', text=action.name)
        layout.operator('view3d.print_action_export_status')

class OT_dynamic_property(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = 'view3d.print_action_export_status'
    bl_label = 'Print'
    bl_options = {'REGISTER'}

    def execute(self, context):
        print('*' * 5)
        for action in bpy.data.actions:
            print("%s:\t%s" % (action.name, action.EX_export_this))
        return {'FINISHED'}

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_module(__name__)
    bpy.types.Action.EX_export_this = bpy.props.BoolProperty(default=False)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

It's easy, and there's not a lot we need to do. Upon execution, the code above will list the property:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Thanks alot, it´s not perfect but it works fine so i´ll just go with it

Comment: I've try to change the 'dynamic property' : for action in bpy.data.actions:
With : for action in bpy.data.scenes:
But it doesn't work. Does your solution only work with action or it also work with other bpy.data? (I want to create a dynamic check box panel with the Scene.)

Comment: @lucblender: `Scene` is a subclass of `ID`, so it should work. That iteration accesses `Action` class' boolean `EX_export_this` property, which is added on script registration. Within `register()` function, you need to substitute `bpy.types.Action` with `bpy.types.Scene`.

Comment: Sorry for asking question again but is it possible to create a dynamic property panel with string, int, etc... property and not boolean? Edit: I've found it's in registration bpy.types.Scene.RenderTrue = bpy.props.StringProperty(default='Text')

Comment: @lucblender Yes, as long as the data type is supported by [`bpy.props`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_69_7/bpy.props.html).

Answer (score 9):

In addition to what Adhi suggested, you can use [`CollectionProperty`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_67_release/bpy.props.html#bpy.props.CollectionProperty) in your operator to store key value pairs (where keys are name of the action and values are boolean values). For this to work you must...

- create a subclass of [`PropertyGroup`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_67_release/bpy.types.PropertyGroup.html) that will hold single key-value pair.
- populate this collection from [`Operator.invoke`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_67_release/bpy.types.Operator.html#invoke-function) method (you might already have it)

So the code goes like this:

```
import bpy
from bpy_extras.io_utils import ExportHelper
from bpy.props import *

class ActionSelProperty(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    name = StringProperty(name="Action Name")
    export = BoolProperty(name="Export", description="Exporet this action", default=True)

class ExportTSA(bpy.types.Operator, ExportHelper):
    bl_idname = "test.export_tsa_op"
    bl_label = "Export TSA"

    actionprop = CollectionProperty(name="Actions", type=ActionSelProperty, description="Select actions to exporet")
    filename_ext = "*.*" # Only needed if subclassing `ExportHelper`

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        for aname in bpy.data.actions.keys():
            self.actionprop.add().name = aname
        wm = context.window_manager
        wm.fileselect_add(self)
        return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout

        for aindx in range(len(self.actionprop)):
            row = layout.row()
            row.prop(self.actionprop[aindx], "export", text=self.actionprop[aindx].name)

    def execute(self, context):
        for aprop in self.actionprop:
            print("%s:\t%s" % (aprop.name, aprop.export))
        return {'FINISHED'}

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_module(__name__)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

In this case,  `name` is a key and `export` is a boolean value.

PS: Invoke by searching `Export TSA`. Screenshots:

[image] [image]

This may not be perfect, but you can investigate more! :)

HTH

Comment: I tried your implementation and it works, but adhi´s seemed a little bit simpler but thanks anyways, i appreciate the help

Comment: Love your answer, this is definitely the right way to do it, though I must admit, adhi's answer is very interesting.